# Count occurences of pattern with whitespaces in a file using bash

Tags: bash, count, grep

as the title suugest, I would like to count the occurences of a pattern involving spaces or tabs. I have tried:

```
grep -o ' 2L ' file | wc -l
```

and

```
grep -o '\s2L\s' file | wc -l
```

but it printed a smaller number (only 1) than

```
grep -o 2L file | wc -l
```

which prints 14567. The pattern `[space]2L[space]` occures frequently in a file.
Your soultions?

Here I present the first lines of `cat file` output:
`2L^Isplign_na_dbEST_ncbi^Imatch^I16299682^I16299851^I.^I-^I.^IID=Splign:0568174_na_dbEST_ncbi;Name=RP003180722.5prime-GH911198-na_dbEST_ncbi_20090309-splign;program=splign;programversion=1.0;sourcename=na_dbEST_ncbi;target_type=EST;Target=GH911198 1 171 +$
2L^Isplign_na_dbEST_ncbi^Imatch_part^I16299682^I16299851^I100^I-^I.^IName=:ncbi_2178736;Parent=Splign:0568071_na_dbEST_ncbi;target_type=EST;Target=GH773194 1 170 +$
2L^Isplign_na_dbEST_ncbi^Imatch_part^I16299682^I16299851^I100^I-^I.^IName=:ncbi_2178839;Parent=Splign:0568174_na_dbEST_ncbi;target_type=EST;Target=GH911198 1 171 +$
2L^Isplign_na_dbEST_ncbi^Imatch_part^I16299682^I16299851^I99.41^I-^I.^IName=:ncbi_2178729;Parent=Splign:0568064_na_dbEST_ncbi;target_type=EST;Target=GH807525 1 170 +$
2L^Isplign_na_dbEST_ncbi^Imatch_part^I16299682^I16299851^I99.41^I-^I.^IName=:ncbi_2178751;Parent=Splign:0568086_na_dbEST_ncbi;target_type=EST;Target=GH890956 1 178 +$
2L^Isplign_na_dbEST_ncbi^Imatch^I16299682^I16299850^I.^I-^I.^IID=Splign:0568097_na_dbEST_ncbi;Name=RP003087707.5prime-GH857137-na_dbEST_ncbi_20090309-splign;program=splign;programversion=1.0;sourcename=na_dbEST_ncbi;target_type=EST;Target=GH857137 4 172 +$`

and a portion of `less` output:

```
##gff-version 3
##sequence-region 2L -204333 23011544
##species  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?id=7227
##genome-build FlyBase r5.21
2L      FlyBase chromosome_band -204333 1326937 .       +       .       ID=band-21_chromosome_band;Name=band-21
2L      FlyBase chromosome_band -204333 22221   .       +       .       ID=band-21A_chromosome_band;Name=band-21A
2L      FlyBase chromosome_band -204333 -153714 .       +       .       ID=band-21A1_chromosome_band;Name=band-21A1
2L      FlyBase breakpoint      -204333 -204333 .       .       .       ID=Df(2L)ED50001:bk1_breakpoint;Name=Df(2L)ED500
```

Comment: `grep -o '[[:blank:]]2L[[:blank:]]' file | wc -l` but include your sample data in question

Comment: Save a pipe, use `grep -c`.

Comment: anubhava, it still prints 1

Comment: What is output of `cat -A file`

Comment: The file is so long, that I can call `cat -A file` output as a flowing matrix sort of screensaver. However, I see that 2L is sometimes followed by ^ in `cat` output: at the beginning of a new line appears as `2L^`.

Comment: Post the first 10 lines or so (or first 100 characters if they are extremely long spaghetti lines)

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: It sounds to me the file is not a plain text file. Please start with `xxd file | less` to see what is inside.

Comment: @Cornholio That works if you want to count lines or if you know that the pattern won't occur more often than once per line, but otherwise you miss multiple occurrences on the same line.

Comment: Indeed, I want a single occurence per line. It is a gff file - compiled sequences of the genome.

Comment: Now how about either `hexdump -Cv -n512 file` or `xdd -g1 -l512 file` and the output of `file file` so we can get a handle on what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have pattern `2L` right at line start and a tab afterwards.

You can use this simple awk to get the count:

```
awk '$1 == "2L"{++c} END{print c}' file
```

Using `grep` it will be:

```
grep -c '^2L[[:blank:]]' file
```

Comment: Haven't you missed a ` ' ` in the last solution?

Comment: No,` awk` command was fine but `grep` command had some typo that is also fixed now.

Comment: I tried `grep -c '^2L[[:blank:]]'  file` and it seems to work (around 13 000 results). Thank you!